# WxGTK won't link under Arch Linux

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets, archlinux

So I have this Wx application written in C++ that I've tested under Linux Mint, Ubuntu, and even Mac but under Arch Linux it doesn't seem to link correctly. I've installed the wxgtk library required and the compilation works fine but when it gets to the linking stage I get a lot of output saying that none of the Wx methods could be found. wx-config --libs output looks correct to me so I'm not sure what's causing the problem. I will post my Makefile if necessary but it seems this issue is only specific to Arch Linux so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is bashing their head over this I changed the linker line from

```
g++ `wx-config --libs` -o $(OBJS)
```

to

```
g++ -o $(OBJS) `wx-config --libs`
```

The reason for this is detailed in rodrigo's comment below.

Comment: When linking, the order of the files presented on the command-line might be an issue. It's best to always place libraries at the end.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I didn't really know that and man have I worked on ALOT of C/C++ projects and have never seen an issue with the order pop up while linking, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: From `man ld`: "If the archive [library] defines a symbol which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s) from the archive.  However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing later on the command line __will not cause the linker to search the archive__ again."

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for finding that.